# insert into values where

Tags: sql, select, insert

I'm not proficient with SQL and Ive been looking for a solution to which is probably a simple one for those that know what they're doing.

I have a two column table with user_id and group_id. It stores all the groups a particular user is a part of.

i.e.

```
user_id, group_id
2        4
2        6
2        7
3        4
4        6
4        7
```

You get the idea.

All I want to do is insert the user_id and new group_id (let's say 10) records into the table for those who are part of a specific group_id (like 6). I Have been trying different `INSERT WITH SELECT` statements but keep getting errors. I search around, but couldn't get one to work properly from the examples given.

Could anyone help me out?

Comment: Which RDBMS (Oracle, SQL Server, PostgreSQL, MySql, etc) are you using?

Comment: Please edit your question and include the query you tried and how the result differs from what you want

Answer (score 1):

```
insert into table (user_id, group_id)   
values (12,6), (13,6)
```

or

```
insert into table (user_id, group_id)  
select user_id, 10 
from table 
where group_id = 6
```

Comment: add update code too, for generic question your need to use generic answer

Comment: and what if you don't know this '6'?

Comment: @ErasmoOliveira The question asked about insert.

Comment: @miraclefoxx If you don't know the values then you can't insert them.

Answer (score 1):

Check This..

```
insert into yourtable (user_id,group_id)
Select user_id , 10 as Newgroup_id /*The new Group id */
From yourtable 
where group_id = 6 /*OldGroupID*/
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Worked like a charm. Just what I needed. :)